# How to reach a Schema in Orcale with python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

OK so this is a revision. I am new to Python and Oracle so I total worded this wrong. this is what i am trying to do.

Connect to root Database -> target specific schema, inside of schema is a Table, inside of that table are a bunch of nested tables that show up as tabs in oracle developer.

So I am able to connect to the DB and using the code above I can reach the schema and the main table in the schema but not sure how to reach the nested tables with in the table that is inside of the schema.

Basically i am wanting my connection to connect and put me inside of tha table inside of the schema as the parent I am working in.

So like in Oracle developer I can choose the schema then click on the table and then click on whichever of the nested tables I want.

Sorry for this terrible description I am not really sure how else to word it.

```py
import cx_Oracle

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('HostName', 'PORT', sid='12345') # if needed, place an 'r' before any parameter in order to address special characters such as '\'.

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'UserName', password='123456', dsn=dsn) # if needed, place an 'r' before any parameter in order to address special characters such as '\'. For example, if your user name contains '\', you'll need to place 'r' before the user name: user=r'User Name'

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from Schema.Table') # use triple quotes if you want to spread your query across multiple lines

for row in c:
    print (row[0], '-', row[1]) # this only shows the first two columns. To add an additional column you'll need to add , '-', row[2], etc.

#conn.close()
```

Comment: what is Schema.Table supposed to be?  Please edit the question and show complete errors.

Comment: Lets say the Schema is DOGS and the table is DogsLeash.   The issue I am having is the Schema houses a table that has nested tabs/tables.  So inside DogsLeash there are 10 tabs all with ables.  When I run the script the way i have it just to see if it is connected it just started spewing columns non stop and I have to end it manually.  So I am doing something wrong.  If I try and add the SCHEMA into the cx_oracle.makedsn it tells me invalid syntax.

Comment: sorry still don't understand.  What is a "tab?" Are you talking about [Oracle Nested Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/multilevel-collection-types.html#GUID-4BC4D2E9-18D2-439A-B0F7-2CD8C9BEA353) ? which is something completely different.  It would be best if you edit the questions and show these table definitions as an example.

Comment: You do a `SELECT *` so you will get all columns.  You don't have a  `WHERE` clause so you will get all rows.   If your problem is too much data, fix those problems.  For example add something like `WHERE id < 100` to your `SELECT`.  If you are trying to achieve something else, update your question to explain what.  Reviewing the cx_Oracle [samples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/main/samples) will be useful.  Also see the cx_Oracle [documentation](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: "but then trying to select the schema is presenting an issue" - if you have any errors, please, post error text as plain text. If you do not know where to start with, then describe your requirements with some examples, provide sample code (DDL and DML for the database) and the result you want to see for this sample code. Basically, you cannot select from schema, because schema itself doesn't contain data. So your question is completely unclear.

Comment: I reworded the question so maybe it helps you understand what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tables created by this [Node.js example](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/selectnestedcursor.js), you can query "nested tables" in Python like:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = """SELECT country,
                  CURSOR(SELECT name
                         FROM no_nc_people p
                         WHERE p.addresskey = a.addresskey
                         ORDER by name
                  ) as NC
           FROM no_nc_address a
           ORDER BY country"""
    for r in cursor.execute(sql):
        print(r)
```

the output is:

```
('Austria', <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to cj@localhost/orclpdb1>>)
('Brazil', <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to cj@localhost/orclpdb1>>)
('Chile', <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to cj@localhost/orclpdb1>>)
```

SQL Developer is showing you that cursors exist and letting you click and fetch
from just the ones you want.

You can program the equivalent in Python. The most basic implementation is to fetch all nested cursors:

```
def printcur(c):
    while True:
        r = c.fetchone()
        if r is None:
            break
        print(r[0])

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = """SELECT country,
                  CURSOR(SELECT name
                         FROM no_nc_people p
                         WHERE p.addresskey = a.addresskey
                         ORDER by name
                  ) as NC
           FROM no_nc_address a
           ORDER BY country"""
    for r,c in cursor.execute(sql):
        print('Country:', r)
        printcur(c)
```

The output is:

```
Country: Austria
Alice
David
Country: Brazil
Frank
Country: Chile
Bruce
Christine
Erica
```

So `printcur()` is just being called on the "cursor" that represents each nested cursor.